# Writing 2D array into binary file in C (getting strange results)

Tags: c, io, binaryfiles

I'm using this code to write the file:

```
FILE *f = fopen("out/solution.raw", "wb");
int i, j;
//SIZE = 512
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    fwrite(matrix[i], 1, SIZE, f);
}   

fclose(f);
```

The problem is that when I open the file, it 3 '0' between the numbers, here are 2 screenshots to help you understand what I mean:

This is what I should be getting:

[image: This is what I should be getting:]

And this is what I'm getting:

[image: My output]

As you can see my code is correctly writing each number, but there are three 0 between each number and I have no idea why.

I've also tried this:

```
fwrite(matrix[i], sizeof(matrix[i][0]), SIZE, f);
```

But none seems to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

my matrix is declared as a 2D array of ints, as I need to do some operations with those numbers:

```
matrix = (int**)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int*));
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    matrix [i] = (int*)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(int*));
}
```

I've tried your solution but I can't assign an unsiged char to an int, so I've tried casting it and I get this warning:

cast from pointer to integer of different size.

```
unsigned char to_write;
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    to_write = (unsigned char)matrix[i];
    fwrite(&to_write, 1, 1, f);
}
```

(code used)

After that this is what I'm getting:

[image]

And btw, my data is unsigned.

Comment: you're using `int32` when you should use `unsigned char`. show the declaration of `matrix`

Comment: `int **` is not a 2D array of anything. It's a pointer to pointer, a completely different type. If you want a 2D array (i.e. an array of arrays), use one, there are enough examples how to do it right on SO and elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry @toohonestforthissite English is not my first lenguage and it has led to me using the term "2D array" wrongly. I'm using an int** matrix, and I want to write the content of it in a binary file.

Comment: @Sefean A matrix **is** a synonym for a 2D array here. Please read the second half of my previous comment, which says if you want a matrix/2D array, you should use one. Don't use inappropriate data structures.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite The thing is I strictly need to use a pointer to pointer, because later this will be used in MPI wich will require me to send each "line" of the matrix, one by one, that's why I'm using pointer to pointer.

Comment: @Sefean: How does using a 2D array keep you from accessing single rows? Please consult your/a C textbook.

Comment: @Sefean see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matrix[i]` is a pointer on 32-bit integers. Even if you assign values that hold in 8 bits, that doesn't "compress" the data when you're writing to a binary stream (plus you probably don't write the 512 values but only 512/4 = 128 values)

Your machine is little endian, so you get the LSB first, then 3 zeros, for each value.

So change the type of `matrix[i]` from `int32_t *` to `char *` or `unsigned char *` depending on what you need, make sure your values are in 8-bit range, and you can use `fwrite` like you're planning to.

If you cannot change the data type of `matrix`, use a loop to convert the values

```
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    uint8_t to_write = matrix[i];  // assign/truncate for 0/255 range
    fwrite(&to_write, 1, 1, f);
}
```

if your data is signed, you have to use `int8_t`. But in that case, you're not going to be able to write `a0` as 160.

EDIT: your edit shows the real type of `matrix`. `matrix[i]` is a pointer on data, so you need to use a double loop to dump it, else you're copying the address of the array, not the value

```
for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
   const int *row = matrix[i];
   for(j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
   {
       uint8_t to_write = row[j];  // assign/truncate for 0/255 range
       fwrite(&to_write, 1, 1, f);
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm gonna answer you in the question so you can see the code properly.

Comment: `uint8_t` or `int8_t` would be other options since `int32_t` was in use.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I get the same problem.

Comment: First issue to resolve is to use a 2D array, not a pointer to pointer.

Comment: oh, welcome back :) yes, OP edited. So I edited as well